# jQuery matching a selector with regex

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I have a form and wanna reuse some code (DRY).

Here is a part of the form:

```
  <select id="user_country" name="user[country]"><option value="AT">Austria</option>
```

I wanna match the word `user` depending on the

ID

```
xxxxxx_country
```

or on the NAME

```
xxxxxx[country]
```

how can I get the `xxxxxx` ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the DOM element:

```
theElement.id.split('_')[0];
```

Or using regex:

```
theElement.id.match(/[^_]+/)[0];
```

If not, you can find it like this:

```
var theElement = $('select[id$="_country"]')[0];
```

Comment: Usernames could theoretically contain "_", you probably want to use every index but the last one instead of only the first index